# Identify this song "Earth Level Dancing Lines" (Android Game)?

Tags: identify-this-song, videogame-soundtrack

I am overwhelmed because I listened to this song in the game *Dancing Lines*, at the Earth level, but I can't identify it. Could it be a song from a famous film or something?

[The Song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fhuKIzKJ9_U) is between 0:11 and 0:52.

Comment: before answer here i google this but dont found results and also try shazam the song neither works. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The song is called *The Earth*, by Łukasz Michalski﻿.

Here is a [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7hr4dmBY4Fk) to his official account, he composed some other songs for the same game.